# Looping through controls in each frame in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with multiple frames, within each frames are multiple option buttons. I want to loop through each option button within each frame.

My current code works like this, but here I hardcoded `Me.f_FileType.Controls` and instead I want to dynamically change it for each frame, `frm`, in my Userform.

```vb
Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()

Dim ctl As msforms.control
Dim frm As msforms.control
Dim obArr() As Variant
Dim n As Integer: n = 1

For Each frm In Me.Controls
If TypeName(frm) = "Frame" Then

    ' Counting number of specific control type
    For Each ctl In Me.f_FileType.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "OptionButton" Then
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next ctl

    ' Redimensioning array to match
    ReDim obArr(1 To n, 1 To 2)
    n = 1

    ' Populating array
    Debug.Print "Option buttons in " & frm.Caption & ":"
    For Each ctl In Me.f_FileType.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "OptionButton" Then
            obArr(n, 1) = ctl.TabIndex
            obArr(n, 2) = ctl.Caption
            Debug.Print "Option button '" & obArr(n, 2) & "' with the tabindex value " & obArr(n, 1)
        End If
    Next ctl

End If
Next frm

End Sub
```

Comment: You are already identifying the `Frames` in your code in the line `If TypeName(frm) = "Frame" Then`

Comment: Next loop should be `For Each ctl In frm.Controls` instead of `For Each ctl In Me.f_FileType.Controls` to loop through all the controls in a Frame

Comment: But once you identify that frame, you can add another loop inside it to loop through the controls.

Comment: Thanks I mistakenly wrote `Me.frm.controls` before hardcoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are already looping to find a Frame in line:**

```
If TypeName(frm) = "Frame" Then
```

**All you have to do is change the line:**

```
For Each ctl In Me.f_FileType.Controls
```

**to:**

```
For Each ctl In frm.Controls
```